# MVC4 jQueryMobile SQL phoneGap from responsive to app

Tags: android, ios, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have an MVC4 Web Application with Sql-Server/jQuery/WebApi that I want to expand to mobile.

I know that using the "mobile" word in the cshtml file view is displayed only on mobile devices, but how do I configure my project to present the pages to work only on mobile devices (except resolutions like iPad) and be prepared to create a phonegap project to export to iOS and Android?

The idea is to start in a responsive web version for mobile devices and to expand to app stores, so I can have a bigger number of devices that can access my website.

Comment: phonegap uses pure HTML so none of ASP features would work there.

Comment: Hi thanks, but how do you switch from desktop to pure html for mobile devices in mvc4?

Comment: you won't do it as easy as you'd like. (I'm not an ASP developer). You could visit your page, get source in browser and make clean html template of it. But for dynamic content you will have to write some javascript AJAX code.